# No color on donut after applying bump and displacement

Tags: bump

After following the part 4, level 2 tutorial about bump and displacement the colors on my donut disappeared. Do anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advanced.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have a close look at the Principled BSDF and the Material Output nodes. They are not connected.

You probably used the Node Wrangler's preview feature and now the BSDF is no longer connected to the material output. Just reconnect them and the color should be back.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of things the *principled BSDF* (the big green one) isn't connected to the output of the *output node*. All you need to do is delete the viewer node and connect two two nodes together and it should work!

Im sorry if that was condecending but good luck with blender and have a good day! :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)